# Finger (Sensor) Shaking Detection

Tags: unity, c#, geometry

I want to make the user be able to shake a certain object through the phone's sensor.
I have drag&drop mechanics now, and I want this shake to be directly related to that mechanics.
How would that happen:

1. The user clicks on an object and starts dragging it
2. Without releasing his finger, he started to move the object from side to side at a fast pace
3. The object realized it was being shaken and the event occurred.

I attach drawings as I see it. The line means the drag route:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Vaillancourt Nothing so far. I have very little knowledge of linear algebra, so I'm counting on someone to help me with pseudocode or a verbal implementation.

Comment: Do you just want horizontal shakings like in your example or do you want to detect vertical ones as well?

Comment: @Arian_ki both types